# Geometric proof that $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 = | \vec a | |\vec b | \cos(\varphi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I want to define the scalar product by $\vec a \cdot \vec b = | \vec a | |\vec b | \cos(\varphi)$ and derive $\vec a \cdot \vec b = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2$. Algebraically, this is no problem (we can just expand the vectors in the standard basis).

How do I show this by using only elementary geometry? I've drawn the areas of the rectangles $a_1 b_1$, $a_2 b_2$ and $| \vec a | \cos(\varphi) \cdot |\vec b | $but I don't see why they should be equal.

/edit: I'm really interested in the general case and in using elementary geometry, not in getting an elegant proof which involves rotations.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be looking at rectangles: think parallelograms.

Comment: Prove it for $\,b_1=1, b_2=0\,$, then show that the dot product commutes with scalars and is invariant to rotations.

Comment: @NickPeterson: I don't see how to draw $a_1 b_1$ as a parallelogram. Could you elaborate (and please note my recent edit to the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to compute the (square of the) red length two ways, and equate the two.

[image]

On the one hand, Pythagoras tells us that the red length is the hypotenuse of a right triangle, whose legs have length $|a_1 - b_1|$ and $|a_2 - b_2|$, so the square of its length must be $$|a_1 - b_1|^2 + |a_2 - b_2|^2 = (a_1 - b_2)^2 + (a_2 - b_2)^2$$

On the other hand, the Law of Cosines tells us that the square of the red length is $$|a|^2 + |b|^2 - 2|a||b|\cos(\varphi) = (a_1^2 + a_2^2) + (b_1^2 + b_2^2) - 2|a||b|\cos( \varphi )$$

Since these are equal, we have $(a_1 - b_2)^2 + (a_2 - b_2)^2 = (a_1^2 + a_2^2) + (b_1^2 + b_2^2) - 2|a||b|\cos( \varphi )$

It looks like a mess, but if you multiply out the squares on the left side, you get a bunch of cancellation (with the squares on the right), and before long, $a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 = |a||b|\cos( \varphi )$ pops out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks good. I need to connect it with my previous effort which I will do tomorrow.

Comment: You're welcome, thank you, and that sounds fine to me!

Comment: Ok, this is a bit more complicated than I would have liked but it solves my query. I guess it just isn't possible to think about this relationship using rectangles in a really simple way.

Comment: There may be a nicer way, using a parallelogram generated by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ (half of it's in the drawing here). I haven't seen it yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't think the thing to do is to look at rectangles. First, prove that the dot product is invariant under rotations (this is a little circular, since some people would say rotations are defined by being linear maps preserving the dot product and orientation).

Then, line one of those vectors up with the $x$-axis. Without a loss of generality, say $\vec{b}$ is along the $x$-axis. Then it has components $(b_1,0)$ in the standard basis. The projection of $\vec{a}$ onto the $x$-axis is $|\vec{a}|\cos(\varphi)$. That is $a_1= |\vec{a}|\cos(\varphi)$. At the same time, $|\vec{b}| = b_1$, since it is lined up on the $x$-axis. So, then we obviously have $a_1b_1= |\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos(\varphi)$. But, since it is rotationally invariant, this holds in general.

Answer (score 0):

**An other (more geometric) way:**

Consider the following draw

[image]

We denote $\alpha :=\angle(a,b)$. Moreover, $a^\perp=(-a_2,a_1)$ is a vector that is perpendicular to $a$ with same norm than $a$ (i.e. $\alpha +\beta =\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\|a\|=\|a^\perp\|$). You have that $$a_1b_1+a_2b_2=\left|\begin{array}{cc} b_1&-a_2\\b_2&a_1\end{array}\right|=\det(b,a^\perp)=\text{Area}\big(P(b,a^\perp)\big),$$
where $P(b,a^\perp)$ is the parallelogram generated by $b$ and $a^\perp$.

We know that $\beta =\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha $ and that $$\text{Area}\big(P(b,a^\perp)\big)=\|b\|\|a^\perp\|\sin(\beta ).$$
Since $$\|a^\perp\|=\|a\|\quad \text{and}\quad \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha \right)=\cos(\alpha ),$$
we finally get $$a_1b_1+a_2b_2=\|a\|\|b\|\cos\big(\angle(a,b)\big),$$
as wished.

---

**An other (more analytically) way:**

[image]

Let $a=(a_1,a_2)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)$. Denote $\bar x$ the $x-$axis, $\hat a=\angle(\bar x,a)$ the (oriented) angle between $\bar x$ and $a$ and $\hat b=\angle (\bar x,b)$; the (oriented) angle between $\bar x$ and $b$. Finally, denote $\|\cdot \|$ the Euclidian norm.

- In one hand,
  $$\cos(\hat a)=\frac{a_1}{\|a\|}\quad \text{and}\quad \sin(\hat a)=\frac{a_2}{\|a\|}$$
  $$\cos(\hat b)=\frac{b_1}{\|b\|}\quad \text{and}\quad \sin(\hat b)=\frac{b_2}{\|b\|}.$$
- In the other hand, $$\angle(a,b)=\hat b-\hat a,$$

and thus \begin{align*}
\cos\big(\angle(a,b)\big)&=\cos(\hat b-\hat a)\\
&=\cos(\hat a)\cos(\hat b)+\sin(\hat a)\sin(\hat b)\\
&=\frac{a_1b_1}{\|a\|\|b\|}+\frac{a_2b_2}{\|a\|\|b\|}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $$\|a\|\|b\|\cos\big(\angle(a,b)\big)=a_1b_1+a_2b_2,$$
as wished.